# Is it possible to use 3.0 TB HDD in Windows - 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is it possible to use 3.0 TB HDD in Windows -7 ?

I have been using 2.0 TB HDD to store my big files. It has Crashed so I want to replace it with a 3.0 TB Western Digital internal HDD.

I do have a 2.0 TB external USB back up HDD ( Seagate GoFlex ) & want to clone it to 3.0 TB HDD to transfer all the files.

I have Acronis True Image Home to clone the backed Up Seagate 2.0 TB GoFlex HDD to new 3.0 TB WD HDD.

Is this possible & how do I go about it before I purchase a new 3.0 TB WD internal HDD ?

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems if this is going to be a secondary disk.  If you want to boot from it you may run into difficulty, depending on your computer.

Comment: windows can very well manage it...
problem may lie with your motherboard.

Comment: It all depends on your motherboard.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check your other hardware. Windows 7 supports it, but the SATA controller on your motherboard might not. It's to do with legacy addressing.

http://www.pcworld.com/article/235088/everything_you_need_to_know_about_3tb_hard_drives.html

Comment: +1 for the link.  Note that if you are running the 64-bit version of Windows 7, and the disk is secondary (not a boot disk) then you shouldn't have any problems, no matter what hardware you're using.